# Shift wise datetime checking in sql server query

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have one problem with sql queries in one of my projects. Actually, I have to check one DateTime column in some table with three shifts, i.e., I have to get the records based on RegisteredDateTime column which is falling in respective shifts. We have the following shift timings, the shifts will be in 24 hr formats

```
Shift1 : 07:00:00-12:00:00
Shift2 : 12:00:00-22:00:00
Shift3 : 22:00:00-07:00:00
```

My problem is I am getting the records correctly in shift1 and shift2, but not the records lies in shift3. I am going rounds, to solve this. I am using the following search query to fetch the records in all the shifts

```
SELECT        RequestNumber
FROM            Table
WHERE (CONVERT(Time, RegisteredDateTime) BETWEEN '" & Shift1.Split("-")(0) &"' AND ' " & Shift1.Split("-")(1) & "')
```

The above query is used for Shift1, similarly I am checking for Shift2 and Shift3 also.

Hello every one, finally the idea given by @ AnandPhadke worked for me, its the final query i am using

```
 Dim StartNumber As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(Shft3Arr(1).Split(":")(0))
 Dim EndShift As String = (StartNumber - 1) & ":59:59"
 query += "(CONVERT(Time, Complaints.RegisteredDateTime) >= '" + Shft3Arr(0) + "') OR  (CONVERT
(Time, DATEADD(DD, 1, Complaints.RegisteredDateTime)) <= '" + EndShift + "')"
```

Comment: Can you change the schema so you're storing shift start and shift duration? It would be more logical imo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use these conditions:

For shift1

```
WHERE CONVERT(Time, RegisteredDateTime) > convert(time,'07:00:00') and CONVERT(Time, RegisteredDateTime) <= convert(time,'12:00:00')
```

For shift2

```
WHERE CONVERT(Time, RegisteredDateTime) > convert(time,'12:00:00') and CONVERT(Time, RegisteredDateTime) <= convert(time,'22:00:00')
```

For shift3

```
WHERE CONVERT(Time,RegisteredDateTime) > convert(time,'22:00:00') and CONVERT(Time,  DATEADD(DD,1,RegisteredDateTime)) <= convert(time,'06:59:59')
```

Comment: @ AnandPhandke, I tried with the query condition which you have provided, but no luck with that.

Comment: here what will be your registered date? I mean will it be alwys the getdate()?

Comment: No, it will be some request booked date. Ok, any how thank you I will check it and update to you.

Comment: hey I have updated my query.In your main query u did not convert string time part to time datatype.Pls check the updated query

Comment: @ AnandPhadke, the query which you have given works but a little bit modification, instead of AND we have to change to OR and we should convert at the time part again. Please, see my latest update for the query that worked for me atlast.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest thing to do here is to **SHIFT** the times (pun intended)!

Your times are 7-12,12-22,22-7*  (7* being next day)

Shift them to 0-5,5-15,15-24 using just a little bit of magic, which will match the date range you are testing against being the `start of the shift`, correct?

```
SELECT RequestNumber
FROM   Table
WHERE  DateAdd(hh,-7,CONVERT(Time, RegisteredDateTime))
       BETWEEN ....
```

That, while nice in logic is not SARGABLE, so we shift the range instead, the opposite way.

```
SELECT RequestNumber
FROM   Table
WHERE  CONVERT(Time, RegisteredDateTime)
       BETWEEN DateAdd(hh,7,@date1) AND DateAdd(hh,7,@date2)
```

Comment: @ Richard, I cant change the shifts like that. We have given the shift timings by our customer, the shifts are according to their working times.

Comment: You completely missed the point. By "shift"ing the times I mean when comparing the times. Adding -7 hours in the WHERE clause effectively "shifts" them because a 7-9 shift after adjusting becomes 0-2 for the purposes of comparing against the date range.

Comment: Sorry, @ Richard. Can you please help me in this. The queries which you have given are some what tricky to understand. I have solved somany problems upto now relating date and time, but this is making me fail.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>Shift 3 is span across 2 days..</strike>

Add these conditions also with your query

```
AND  CONVERT(Time,DATEADD(DD,1,RegisteredDateTime)) < '07:00:00'
AND  CONVERT(Time,RegisteredDateTime) > '07:00:00'
AND  DATEDIFF(DD,CONVERT(DATE,RegisteredDateTime), 
             CONVERT(Date,DATEADD(DD,1,RegisteredDateTime))) <=1
```

This answer is based on  **Richard aka cyberkiwi** answer above. Full credit goes to him.
Please accept his answer if this is working for you..

your shift data is like this:

```
Shift1 : 07:00:00-12:00:00  
Shift2 : 12:00:00-22:00:00  
Shift3 : 22:00:00-07:00:00
```

what you need to do is just set the @shift_start_time  and @shift_end_time based on the shift time

```
declare @shift_start_time time ;
 declare @shift_end_time time;

 IF shift 1:
 select @shift_start_time ='00:00:00'
 select @shift_end_time ='04:59:59'

 IF shift 2:
 select @shift_start_time ='05:00:00'
 select @shift_end_time ='14:59:59'

 IF shift 3:
 select @shift_start_time ='15:00:00'
 select @shift_end_time ='23:59:59'

SELECT RegisteredDateTime 
FROM   t_shift
WHERE  CONVERT(Time, DateAdd(hh,-7,  RegisteredDateTime))
       between @shift_start_time and  @shift_end_time
```

Comment: @ Joe, I appended the condition which you have given along with my condition, but nothing is returned from the query.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not facing any problems in retrieving resutls for shift 1 and shift 2 then then results from shift 3 are just universal set minus the results set of first 2 queries. So say query 1 is for shift 1 and query 2 is for shift 2: Then your query for getting results set for shift 3 will be :

```
select resuestNumber from table where requestNumber not in (query 1) and requestNumber not in(query 2)
```