# SQL Dealing with midnight

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm dealing with (for me) huge SQL problem. I have table called "timeshifts" which as 4 columns:
id, name, from and to. Last two type is TIME.

Now: I have three timeshifts:
06:00 - 14:00
14:00 - 22:00
22:00 - 06:00

Now, I have to find correct shift for current time (which works like a charm), but I can't find a proper records that belong to current shift. IE. table called user_times contains fields with separate date and time values. According to current timeshift I have to find records that belongs to the timeshift. There is no problem for first two shifts, but third one passes midnight and that is my problem.

Here is the query that finds proper shift, event through midnight:

```
SELECT 
  FLOOR(SUM(time_sum) / 60) AS th,
  MOD(SUM(time_sum), 60) AS tm,
  t.* 
FROM
  ur_user_times ut,
  ur_timeshifts t 
WHERE CURTIME() >= IF (
    t.timeshift_to < t.timeshift_from,
    0,
    ADDTIME(t.timeshift_from, "00:15")
  ) 
  AND CURTIME() <= ADDTIME(
    IF (
      t.timeshift_to < t.timeshift_from,
      ADDTIME(t.timeshift_from, "10:00:00"),
      t.timeshift_to
    ),
    "00:15"
  ) 
  AND ut.`date` BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY AND CURDATE()
  AND ut.`start` BETWEEN ADDTIME(t.`timeshift_from`, "-10:00:00") AND ADDTIME(t.`timeshift_to`, "-10:00:00")
  AND ut.user_id = 40
```

ut.start is time value that interests us.

Comment: What's your question? It looks like you already have a query that does what you want.

Comment: Nope. It doesn't. Lets assume that we have 02:32(AM). It should find records between 22:00 and 06:00, but MySQL won't check from 22:00 upwards (through midnight), but downwards.

Comment: You say "Here is the query that finds proper shift, event through midnight". So, again: What's your question?

Comment: I accidently pressed "add comment" ;)

Comment: What is the reason for adding 15 minutes and 10 hours?

Comment: 15 minutes is an internal matter for people who works on my app (IE. when shift is over, they still have 15 minutes to write their worktimes), and 10 hours is to bypass midnight problem that I mentioned in my prev. post :)

Comment: Why 10 hours? That doesn't seem to make any sense.

Comment: @tombom http://i46.tinypic.com/2s6avjl.png http://i47.tinypic.com/261i2dj.png

Comment: @MateuszLisik I meant real data, to play around with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select *
from timeshifts ts,
usertimes ut
where 
(ts.from < ts.to and ut.start >= ts.from and ut.start <= ts.to) OR
(ts.from > ts.to and (ut.start >= ts.from or ut.start <= ts.to))
```

Answer (score 1):

A similar query was posted a few days ago:

Please see this question:

[Shift wise datetime checking in sql server query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12636022/shift-wise-datetime-checking-in-sql-server-query/12639743#12639743)